# Date range in mongodb atlas search using queryString is not working

Tags: mongodb, lucene, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I tried this but with no success (I got an empty result):

```
{
    queryString: {
      defaultPath: 'anyfield',
      query: 'createdAt:["2000-01-30T20:19:53.123Z" TO *]'
    }
}
```

I tried with no quotes too.

And I tried the range operator directly and it works, but my query comes as queryString, so I need it working in queryString.

Comment: could you add sample data?

Comment: sample data: {anyfield: 'any value', createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}

Answer (score 0):

if you have a date object handy great. If not, something like this (pseudocode/JS):

```
date = new Date;
date = date.toISOString();
```

then, here is the query from the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/range/):

```
    {
        "$search": {
           "index": "default",
           "range": {
              "path": "anyField",
              "gte": "2000-01-30T20:19:53.123Z",
              "lte": date,
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried the range operator and it worked, but my query is in lucene query string (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/queryString/), so I need to use the queryString operator with date range. Do you know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

According to mongodb engineers, the queryString operators only accept AND and OR. It doesn't accept any other operator like TO, used in range filters.